# How to explain the result of this polynomial equation?

Tags: regression, interpretation, prediction, polynomial

Lets say that I predicted plant productivity (logy) by precipitation (logx1) and moisture content of soil (logx2). my original data gives me the best result only after taking logarithm on both side of variables.

```
mod <- lm(logy ~ poly(logx1*logx2, 2, raw=TRUE)
```

then I got following coefficients from the model:

```
intercept=6.773; 
logx1*logx2 poly(1) = 2.511; 
logx1*logx2 poly(2) = 0.458
```

With regard to equation, I have 2 questions: 
1. How I can explain the result of this equation
2. How to find the value when precipitation is 0.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How much data do you have? You'd mostly likely do better to have logx1, logx2, their product, their squares, & the product of their squares. (Ie, `lm(logy ~ logx1 + logx2 + logx1^2 + logx2^2 + logx1*logx2 + logx1^2*logx2^2)`.) This is a highly constrained model that is likely to not fit as well. Is there a very well grounded physical theory to justify this version?

Comment: Would you please post - or link to - the original non-log data?

Comment: @ James Phillips. I am sorry how to add data here?

Comment: You can paste it into the question or link to it.

Comment: I have updated above

Comment: `poly()` produces orthogonal polynomials by default, so the coefficients don't map onto the original variables. You should manually enter each term you want rather than using `poly()` to expand the polynomials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from the 3D scatterplot, the posted data seems rather noisy with both a "vertical" section and a "flat" section. The best I could find from an equation search was "Y = a * pow(X1, b) + c * pow(X2, d) + Offset" with fitted parameters a = 2.6908392707633102E+03, b = 3.4211996168376331E+00, c = 2.8379254883958050E+05, d = 2.8577605809712245E-04, and Offset = -2.8395222685511003E+05 giving RMSE = 154.6 and R-squared = 0.38

[image: scatter]

[image: surface]

Comment: @ James Phillips. Thank you so much. yes, data has a lot of noice. That is why I tried to use logarithmic transformation. I don't know that was right way to handle this kind of problem. Did you use specific software to do this or R? Actually all this thing are exactly what I want. to obtain RMSE & MR (%) etc. Can you tell me how to run this model in R?

Comment: My zunzun.com open source Python online curve fitting and surface fitting web site has a 3D "function finder" that I used for the equation search. I pasted your data into the online interface for this equation at http://zunzun.com/Equation/3/Power/Power%20D%20With%20Offset/ and then hit the "Submit" button.

Comment: thanks again for your kind help and sharing this very usefull website as well.